# A question regarding bounded linear functional

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations

Let $(f_n)$ be a bounded sequence of bounded linear functionals on a real normed linear space $X$. Then there exits a linear functional $f\in X^*$ such that $\liminf\limits_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)\leq f(x)\leq \limsup\limits_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)$ for all $x\in X$.

I proceed as follows: Since for each $x\in X$, $(f_n(x))$ is a bounded real sequence, by Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem there exists a subsequence $(f_{n_k})$ of $(f_n)$ such that $(f_{n_k}(x))$ converges. We define $f(x)=\lim\limits_{k\to \infty}f_{n_k}(x)$ for all $x\in X$. The very first problem I face is in showing $f$ to be linear. Once it can be shown to be linear, the problem is solved. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ switched around?  Wouldn't $\limsup f_n(x) = \infty$?

Comment: $(f_n)$ is a bounded sequence and so for each $x\in X$, $(f_n(x))$ is a bounded sequence of real numbers. Thus $\limsup f_n(x)$ must be finite.

Comment: @Anupam The sequence $\{n_k\}$ depends on $x$ so there is no hope of proving that $f$ is linear. I think this requires Hahn Banach Theorem. See the arguments used to define Banach limits.